# Como fixar o "charset" de um documento XML?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, utf-8

Tenho esse código

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://crossorigin.me/http://www.acidigital.com/rss/rss_santo.php",
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "application/xml; charset:utf-8",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (re) {

        console.log(re) // documento XML puro

    }
})
```

Acontece que o documento XML dessa request (http://www.acidigital.com/rss/rss_santo.php) vem com os caracteres especiais substituídos por "�".

Comment: No source do XML se vê a declaração ISO-8859-1 na primeira linha: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> E você esta tratando como utf-8 no seu código. Trabalhar isso seria o ponto de partida.

Comment: @Bacco só quero substituir os � pelos caracteres corretos. Na verdade todas as letras acentuadas ficam assim.

Comment: Quase bacco, e utilize `contentType: "application/xml; charset:ISO-8859-1"` e não UTF-8

Comment: @KingRider tentei, da no mesmo.

Comment: Deve ser seu php tem algum errado charset e coloca o returno `utf8_encode("texto texto texto);`

Comment: @KingRider o PHP não é meu, apenas consumo, quando eu pegava esse XML por outra engine de AJAX com proxy vinha sem esse problema.

Comment: @ropbla9 entendi, e vou pensar como converter para você =S

Comment: @ropbla9 Encontrei sobre conversão é `overrideMimeType('text/html;charset=iso-8859-1')` e não tem para jquery e o puro tem (XmlHttpRequest) para resultar, e não encontrei solução jquery para mime. Já fechei o código pronto debaixo esta feito. até mais.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue o código de exemplo:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "https://crossorigin.me/http://www.acidigital.com/rss/rss_santo.php",
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "application/xml; charset:ISO-8859-1",
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: function(charset) {
        charset.overrideMimeType('text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
    },
    success: function (re) {
      xmltemp = $.parseXML(re);
      $texto = $(xmltemp).find('description');
      console.log($texto.text());
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre></pre>
```

Ler sobre XmlHttpRequest tem conversão/manipulação:

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Usando_XMLHttpRequest

até mais

Comment: Perfeito, cara! @KingRider Pode explicar?

Comment: Um propriedade do objeto ajax (http://i.imgur.com/W4h7abN.png) ... encontrei tem mime como overrideMimeType, Esse mime é um formatação. Segue entender http://canaltech.com.br/o-que-e/o-que-e/O-que-e-MIME/